# Exclude non wanted html from Simple Html Dom - PHP

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using HTML Simple Dom Parser with PHP to get title, description and images from a website. The issue I am facing is I am getting the html which I dont want and how to exclude those html tags. Below is the explanation.

Here is a sample html structure which is being parsed.

```
<div id="product_description">
<p> Some text</p>
<ul>
<li>value 1</li>
<li>value 2</li>
<li>value 3</li>
</ul>

// the div I dont want
<div id="comments">
<h1> Some Text </h1>
</div>

</div>
```

I am using below php script to parse,

```
foreach($html->find('div#product_description') as $description)
{
    echo $description->outertext ;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The above code parses everything inside the div with id "product_description". What I want to exclude the div with Id "comments". I tried to convert this into string and then used substr to exclude the last character but thats not working. Dont know why. Any idea about how can I do this? Any approach that will allow me to exclude the div from parsed html will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the elements you don't want by setting their `outertext = ''`:

```php
$src =<<<src
<div id="product_description">
    <p> Some text</p>
    <ul>
        <li>value 1</li>
        <li>value 2</li>
        <li>value 3</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- the div I don't want -->                                                                                                                                        
    <div id="comments">
        <h1> Some Text </h1>
    </div>

</div>
src;

$html = str_get_html($src);

foreach($html->find('#product_description') as $description)
{
    $comments = $description->find('#comments', 0); 
    $comments->outertext = ''; 
    print $description->outertext ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I couldn't understand why did you use $src variable? Will this hold this object $html->find('div#product_description') ?

Comment: No it is just a variable that holds the HTML so I can pass it to `str_get_html` function, just to make the code fully functional for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it without using $html = str_get_html($src); and $src variable. Here is the code which I used.

foreach($html->find('div#ProductDescription_Tab') as $description)
{
 $comments = $description->find('.hsn_comments', 0); 
   $comments->outertext = ''; 
 
  print $description->outertext ;
 
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i figured out myself just use Advanced Html Dom library its totally compatible with simple html dom & by using it you will get much more control. Its very simple to remove what you want from parsed html. For Ex.

```
//to remove script tag
$scripts = $description->find('script')->remove;

//to remove css style tag
$style = $description->find('style')->remove;

// to remove a div with class name findify-element
$findify = $description->find('div.findify-element')->remove;
```

[enter link description here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/)